# remove theme's name from dashboard .. How?

Tags: themes, dashboard

How are you every body

how can remove name of theme in dashboard .. please ..

[image]

You are using K2 RC-8 theme with 10 widgets.

how can remove 'K2 RC-8 theme' ..

please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are to hide the right now widget or to change the theme name in style.css

To remove the right now widget that shows the theme name.
[image]

To change the theme name open style.css and change the theme name in the header.  If your using the WordPress file editor activate another theme before you change the name in the header.

```
 /*
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
Theme URI: http://example.com
Description: My WordPress theme description
Version: .99
Author: My Name
Author URI: http://example.com
*/
```

Comment: oh yeah , the second way I was using it but it doesn't work because I didn't activate another theme before I change the name. Thank you very much Mr Chri